# Eigenvalues: Large Numbers on Diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix. 
>   $\begin{bmatrix} 2019 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 2022 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\ 3 & 6 & 2027 & 12 & 15 \\ 4 & 8 & 12 & 2034 & 20 \\ 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 2043\end{bmatrix}$

Alright, there has to be an easier way to do this than finding the nasty determinant. Can anyone get me going here?

Comment: For starters, consider the nullity of $A-2018I$.

Comment: Is there a typo in the bottom-right element?

Comment: @Arthur Right. Then how do I find the eigenvectors from there? Just factor back in 2018 afterwards?

Comment: If you look at $ A - 2018 I $, you should be able to guess four vectors that are eigenvectors.  Just look at the first column and the second column.  Then the first column and the third column.  Etc.

Comment: You get the last eigenvalue “for free” since the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace.

Answer (score 2):

1. As the comments by [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur) and [ulaff.net](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543468/ulaff-net),
   $$
   A-2018I = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   2 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
   3 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
   4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 \\
   5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25
   \end{pmatrix}
   \overset{\text{Gaussian}}{\underset{\text{elimination}}{\Longrightarrow}} \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   So we have a four dimensional eigenspace w.r.t. the eigenvalue $2018$, a basis of which is
   $$
   \{ (2,-1,0,0,0), (3,0,-1,0,0), (4,0,0,-1,0), (5,0,0,0,-1) \}
   $$
2. As the comment by [amd](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/265466/amd),
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   \operatorname{trace}A &= (2018+1)+(2018+4)+(2018+9)+(2018+16)+(2018+25)  \\
   &= (2018 \times 5) + (1+4+9+16+25) \\
   &= \sum_{i=1}^5\lambda_i = \text{the sum of all eigenvalues}
   \end{align*}
   $$
   So we can find one remaining eigenvalue $2018+55=2073$, and its eigenvector is $(1,2,3,4,5)$ since
   $$ \begin{align*}
   A-2073I &= (A-2018I)-55I \\
   &= \begin{pmatrix}
   1-55 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
   2 & 4-55 & 6 & 8 & 10 \\
   3 & 6 & 9-55 & 12 & 15 \\
   4 & 8 & 12 & 16-55 & 20 \\
   5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25-55
   \end{pmatrix} \\
   & \overset{\text{Gaussian}}{\underset{\text{elimination}}{\Longrightarrow}} \begin{pmatrix}
   -1+\frac{1}{55} & \frac{2}{55} & \frac{3}{55} & \frac{4}{55} & \frac{5}{55} \\
   2 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   3 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
   4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
   5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1
   \end{pmatrix}
   \end{align*} $$